# Python. What does this expression actually do?

Tags: python, lambda

```
[f for f in (lambda x: x, lambda x: x**2) if f(1) == 1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It creates a list with every function in `(lambda x: x, lambda x: x**2)` that returns '1' for the parameter '1'.

Of course, they both do, so this expression is kind of useless. Where did you see it?